# Seam + RESTeasy not working

Tags: java, seam, resteasy

I am trying to do a simple rest service, following several tutorials and documentation but nothing worked.
Mainly this http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.1.GA/reference/en-US/html/webservices.html#d0e21523

I have a whole system implemented with Seam and so I need to reuse many things on it in our rest API.

I have the following in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/seam/resource/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My class looks like this:

```
  @Name("loginApi")
    @Path("/loginapi")
    @Scope(ScopeType.STATELESS)
    public class TestApi {

        @POST
        @Path("/test")
        @Produces("plain/text")
        public String test(){
            return "test ok";

        }

    }
```

According to the documentation there is no need to do anything else for RESTeasy to work.
But if I go to

http://example.com/app/seam/resources/rest/testapi/test

I only get 'Resource not found'.

UPDATE

I could make it work by adding

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
      </servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
      <param-value>/rest</param-value>
   </context-param>
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>       

   <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>path.to.my.class</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Now the service responds but it giving me "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role"

I had the same problem with Jersey, and that is whey I moved to resteasy. So I am in a loop.

Comment: I could make it work by adding `<servlet>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
      </servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
      <param-value>/rest</param-value>
   </context-param>`

Comment: So... you had a JPA/Hibernate lazy initialization error and as a solution you decided to swap out the JAX-RS implementation? That's like having problems with your car engine and then switching to a different garage to repair it.

Comment: That was because Seam states to have official integration with RESTeasy.

Comment: Okay that makes way more sense than what you say in your question, RESTEasy is built by JBoss under the flag of Redhat just like Seam is. In any case as I said, its an error coming from JPA/Hibernate so I don't really see how your code has anything to do with the error. That is not the exact code you have, is it?

Comment: You are right, it's not the exact code. I have another method that tries to bring a list from the datbase. Just now I realised it was missing here. The error messages says there is no open session for hibernate. I thought that if I could properly use RESTEasy with Seam it would be easier to overcome this.

Comment: Looks like the resteasybootstrap is not loading. It is huge portal writen with Seam 2.1.1.GA and I can't find the right version of RESTEasy that works.

Comment: @CarlosJoséDaCosta Which version of JBoss? If 5/6 you should use the resteasy jars that are supplied in the /deployers folder (jax-rs,resteasy-jax-rs and jboss-seam-resteasy)

Comment: @DaveB I have JBoss 5. But I couldn't find these jars in /deployers folder. Where are they supposed to be. I am adding them in the POM.xml as dependencies. Should I download them separately and put them in /deployers?

Comment: @CarlosJoséDaCosta ah looks like they are only included in AS6, you should check the SEAM docs it has a good section on RestEasy

Comment: @DaveB thanks, but I have already checked and re-checked everything there, I tried a lot of different ways, versions, and when I get no errors I get no results too. Looks like there is something in the project conflicting with it and I won't be able use it.

Comment: One interesting thing is that I could do the same kind of thing before in the same project. I called a Seam action that generates a PDF report from a REST method using Jersey with a help of org.jboss.seam.contexts.Lifecycle.beginCall(). But it seams that this report method do not call any lazy hibernate method.

Comment: I also had problems getting RestEasy setup with SEAM but this is with Jboss AS6 so dont think I can help sorry, but FWIW it sounds like your LazyInit exceptions are a different issue, I dont see how they could be related to Resteasy setup

Comment: @DaveB, looks like REST calls are not being controlled by Seam filters. So no session management is done and when a lazy load is need ed it finds not the appropriate session. That is what I think it is happening when I use Jersey. When I use RESTEasy it not even works. The resource servlet is loaded and is called for every request, but the resources are never found. I think will need to move to JBOSS 7 as a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should access it using `http://example.com/app/seam/resource/rest/testapi/test`

I think its not `seam/resources/rest`, it should be `seam/resource/rest`, from your `SeamResourceServlet` url pattern

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: I actually tried http://example.com/app/seam/resource/rest/testapi/test and nothing happens.